# Ecobee3 Wiring With Heat Pump

Tags: hvac

I have an eEcobee3 I've been trying to get working with my HVAC.  The HVAC is a heat pump, with the air handler in the attic.  The current thermostat is a RiteTemp 6025.  It's currently wired up at the thermostat the way the RiteTemp instructions say (the C wire is present and hooked up), except that the W wire from the air handler is connected to the W2 terminal on the thermostat, and the Y wire is interrupted by a float switch for the drip pan.  The RiteTemp operates as expected: cool air when the temperature goes above the threshold, warm air when the temperature drops below the threshold.
[image]

This is how Ecobee says it should be hooked up with AUX heat.
[image]

This is how the RiteTemp is actually hooked up.
[image]

This is how the wires are hooked up at the air handler (the fat yellow wires connect to the skinny yellow wires from the bundles and go to the float switch):
[image]

(I understand the Y wire triggers the condenser, so presumably the float interrupts the yellow connection to kill the HVAC if the pan drain gets clogged and overflows.)

However, when I hook up the Ecobee following the Ecobee instructions, I get hot air when I should be getting cool.  I'm wondering if the fact that the W wire is connected to W1 at the air handler and W2 at the thermostat is messing things up.  But the RiteTemp works as it should, so...?  Is there a reason the white wire would run from W1 at the air handler to W2 at the thermostat?

Comment: If you try to turn the regular heat on, do you get cold air?

Comment: No, I got hot air.

Comment: What make and model is your heat pump's outdoor unit?  Also, which of the O and B terminals on the old thermostat had a wire hooked to it?

Comment: Carrier 38YRA, connected to O.

Comment: Your Ecobee should have a setting that controls when the O/B wire is energized.  Have you tried flipping it yet?

Comment: You mean energize on heat instead of energize on cool?  IIRC that gives me hot air.

Comment: Have you tried setting the O/B wire back to energize on cool, then moving the W wire to W1 on the t-stat?

Comment: No.  The upshot is that I decided to buy another Ecobee off Craigslist this morning.  Installed it, just as the instructions say, and it works to cool now (hopefully it heats in the winter too!).  I think the original one I had has a faulty O/B circuit or something.

Comment: Do let us know if the replacement works properly in the winteritme as well

Comment: I will try to remember.  Worst case, I pop on the "bad" one! :)

Comment: Just following up on this.  The replacement Ecobee worked to heat in the winter.  Guess the original one I bought was faulty in the reversing circuitry somehow.

Comment: Post that followup as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up on this. I got a replacement Ecobee and it worked to heat in the winter (and cool in the summer). Guess the original one I bought was faulty in the reversing circuitry somehow.